# how to track confirm cancel event of alert in code behind in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, alert

My requirement is very simple yet very seems to be complicated !!

I am using C# code and java-script.

I want to use an alert message with confirm / cancel button and i want to track the user click from code behind  say if he has pressed confirm button of alert message or say if he has clicked on cancel button of alert message.

say from c# code behind page i have called confirmDuplicateCustomerCreation

```
function confirmDuplicateCustomerCreation() {
        confirm('Customer with same details already exists. Do you want to continue?')
}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    this,
    this.GetType(), 
    Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    @"<script type='text/javascript'>confirmDuplicateCustomerCreation();</script>", 
    false); 
    Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(CustomerDuplicateFlag.Value); 
} 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function confirmDuplicateCustomerCreation() { 
      if(confirm('Customer with same details already exists. Do you want to continue?'))  
          document.getElementById('<%=CustomerDuplicateFlag.ClientID %>').value = 'Yes'; 
      else 
          document.getElementById('<%=CustomerDuplicateFlag.ClientID %>').value = 'No'; } 
</script> 
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" /> 
<asp:HiddenField ID="CustomerDuplicateFlag" runat="server />
```

then is there any way to track whether the user has clicked on confirm or cancel.... ??

Comment: Hi rene Thanks for your suggestion. But i need to do this via alert message , do you have any idea to implement this via alert box message I just wanted to know can alert messgae event confirm or cancel can be tracked on code behind ?

Comment: In that case you need to grab the boolean that is returned from your call to `yesno = confirm("blah");`, find a hidden checkbox on your form with javascript/jquery, put the value in it and submit your form....

Comment: This answer is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7155993/578411

Comment: The issue with this that while you assign something in a variable  through javascript we cant access the value of the variable until a postback. but i need to access the value in one shot, I mean calling javascript ad assigng variable value upon check and then accesing value form code behind.  But the value is not accessible in code behind until a postback. in next post back i am geting the assigned value which was done hrouh javascript

Comment: Create your own custom alert?

Comment: hoe martin ... how to do so ?/

Comment: You have to choose where you want to handle that userinput. In a webscenario there is either client-side or server-side there is not something between that. If you are in the middle of a server-side code path and you need extra info from the user you only can return a page to get it. Or you have all your info on the clientside (based on the little code you provide woukd mean all your customer data would be send to the browser) and the you could use the return value of confirm. You could dig into Ajax calls but that would make something you asume is easy extremely difficult.

Comment: thanks for sharing the info,
things are simply going in other directio. I just wanted to know i want to call a javascript alert from code behind and on user click of confirm or cancel i just want to track from code behind . How to do that ?

Comment: That is described in the duplicate I linked to.

Comment: what stops you from updating a hidden input field and accessing that over the server-side?

Comment: Dear ,  @deostroll
with reference to your question what stops you from updating a hidden input field and accessing that over the server-side !!
The answere is that where i update the hidden field the value is not updated in the server side until a post back i done but as i need to chech the hidden field in the same flow the hidden field value remains the same you can check by making a text application, u can realize then

Comment: Thnaks rene.. but i dont think i will the solution... i tried everything nothing is working. the reason i found is that i think the javascript alert has the lowest priority when we call from code behind after executing all code then the alert is fired even if the codes are written well below the/ after the  alert code ...

Answer (score 0):

You can save the confirmation value in **HiddenField**, and postback the page to the server by yourself.

### ASPX

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1"
    Text="Submit"
    OnClick="Button1_Click" />

<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenField1"
    OnValueChanged="HiddenField1_ValueChanged" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmDuplicateCustomerCreation() {
        var value = confirm('Customer with same details already exists. Do you want to continue?');
        $('#<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').val(value);
        // By default, OnValueChanged of HiddenField doesn't auto post back to server, 
        // so we need to trigger the post back here by ourself.
        __doPostBack('', '');
    }
</script>
```

### Code Behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
        this,
        this.GetType(),
        UniqueID,
        "confirmDuplicateCustomerCreation();",
        true);
}

protected void HiddenField1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(HiddenField1.Value))
    {
        // User clicked OK at Confirmation   
    }
}
```